# .SendMessage Crashes Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sendmessage

I am using a OverlapSphere to detect all colliders within a certain radius of my object.  I then filter out a few I don't care about.  With the remaining few, I attempt to send a message to those objects to update their render color. Whenever it sends the message, unity freezes.  I tried to do some research and the best thing i could find is that infinite loops can freeze it. But i don't see a potential for that. Here is the code:

Object to send the message:

```
void sendmyMessage(bool status)
{
    Collider[] tiles = Physics.OverlapSphere(gameObject.transform.position, 10);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < tiles.Length)
    {
        if(tiles[i].tag == "Tile")
        {
            //turn light on
            if (status == true)
            {
                tiles[i].SendMessage("Highlight", true);
                i++;
            }

            //turn light off
            if (status == false)
            {
                tiles[i].SendMessage("Highlight", false);
                i++;
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Object Receiving Message:

```
void Highlight(bool status)
{
    //turn light on
    if(status == true)
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
    }

    //turn light off
    if(status == false)
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(1, 1, 1); 
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where/How are you calling `sendmyMessage`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It freezes because of logic `if(tiles[i].tag == "Tile")` here's your answer. Now imagine that object that you collide with has tag "not a tile"? then the loop never ends.

```
foreach(var tile in tiles) {
    if (tile.tag == "Tile") {
        tiles[i].SendMessage("Highlight", status);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just going to simplify his code for him because of the unnecessary if statement but your answer does it perfect

Answer (score 3):

```
while (i < tiles.Length)
{
    if(tiles[i].tag == "Tile")
    {
        //snip
    }     

    // else - loop forever?
}
```

Here's your problem. If the tag != "Tile" then you never increment i.